# HTTP load failed in xcode version 9.3 ios 11 even after adding temporary exception on plist file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, http, nsurlconnection

I am using swift. I saw similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151429/ios-11-and-xcode-9-3-http-load-failed) but there is no answer for that and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974527/how-to-fix-tic-ssl-trust-error-in-ios) but that is using objective c language.

**Error log**:

```
TIC SSL Trust Error [1:0x1c4168340]: 3:0

NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)

Task <00FBDA7D-E906-4BE2-8862-0AD6CAF1A0D7>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1202 [3:-9843])

Task <00FBDA7D-E906-4BE2-8862-0AD6CAF1A0D7>.<1> finished with error - code: -1202
error
```

**screenshot**:

[image: screenshot of plist file]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix ‘TIC SSL Trust Error’ in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974527/how-to-fix-tic-ssl-trust-error-in-ios)

Comment: I am using swift and I am newbie so I don't know how and where to implement that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code from the linked answer in Swift. HTH.

```
class RequestHelper: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {
    func makeRequest(request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) ->() ) {
        let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            completionHandler(data, response, error)
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition,
        URLCredential?) -> () ) {
        guard
            challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust,
            challenge.protectionSpace.host == "yourdomain.com",
            let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust
        else {
            return
        }
        let credential = URLCredential(trust: trust)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
    }
}
```